# json/javascript object array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

Can some body help me to put the below code into an Object, dynamically?

```
var oData = {
        root:{
            name: "root",
            description: "root description",
            checked: false,
            0: {
                name: "item1",
                description: "item1 description",
                checked: true,
                0: {
                    name: "subitem1-1",
                    description: "subitem1-1 description",
                    checked: true,
                    0: {
                        name: "subsubitem1-1-1",
                            description: "subsubitem1-1-1 description",
                            checked: true
                    },
                    1: {
                        name: "subsubitem1-1-2",
                            description: "subsubitem1-1-2 description",
                            checked: true
                    }
                },
                1: {
                    name: "subitem1-2",
                    description: "subitem1-2 description",
                        checked: true,
                    0: {
                        name: "subsubitem1-2-1",
                            description: "subsubitem1-2-1 description",
                            checked: true
                    }
                }               
            },
            1:{
                name: "item2",
                description: "item2 description",
                checked: true,
                0: {
                    name: "subitem2-1",
                    description: "subitem2-1 description",
                    checked: true
                }
            },
            2:{
                name: "item3",
                description: "item3 description",
                checked: true
            }

        }
};
```

::::::Simallar to this on several levels in an Object array:::::::::::::::::::::
Simallar to this on several levels in an Object array
Simallar to this on several levels in an Object array

```
for (var i = 0; i < lenData; i++) {     
            Data.push({
                "name: "item2",
                description: "item2 description",
                checked: true,
            });         
    }
```

Comment: You question does not make any sense. What do you mean in an object, in Javascript that above is already an object.

Comment: That object should have the index key properties removed and be converted to arrays of objects. Your `push()` won't work on an object and those keys are a hinderance

Comment: But I do not know the data before. So I read data from a Model and want to put them dynamically in the objects above.

Comment: How is data created? Fixing the structure will help a lot

Answer (score 0):

What you are proposing is an Array-like Object.
You can either use the Object properties of the array like this:

```js
var rootObjArray = [];
rootObjArray.name = 'Name';
rootObjArray.description = 'Description';
rootObjArray.checked = 'True';

var objArray = []; //Children of root
objArray.name = 'Name';
objArray.description = 'Description';
objArray.checked = 'True';

rootObjArray.push(objArray); //push children into root
```

Which technically still counts as an Array.

Or use the Array.prototype.push when inserting elements to the object like this:

```js
var obj = {
  description : 'description',
  name : 'name',
  checked : 'true',
}

var child = {
  description : 'description',
  name : 'name',
  checked : 'true'
  }

Array.prototype.push.call(obj, child);

document.getElementById('results').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(obj, null, '\t');
```

```html
<pre id="results"></pre>
```

Remember that functions like `pop` or `push` are not for `Object` but for `Array`.

Comment: Thanks, I have to check this.

Comment: Thanks MinusFour, it works good this way. But I have an additional Problem. I would like to fill a tree dynamically. So I do it like this:              if (TreeTableDataLine.PELEMENT == currPelement) {
   element = {
    element : TreeTableDataLine.ELEMENT,
    TEXT : TreeTableDataLine.TEXT,
   };                                     pelement[TreeTableDataLine.PELEMENT][TreeTableDataLine.ELEMENT] = element;